# Oracle XML Extract XPath using values from other columns

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath

I have a CLOB that contains an XML that has information for each row in a detail table. I want to extract the node text from the XML that applies to just the current detail row.  The XPath for the extract would say essentially `[@Line_ID=X]` where X is the current row's `LINE_ID` value.  Currently, I can only see how to hard-code the XPath in the extract command.  The following SQL Fiddle shows the problem and the hard-coded XPath returning the wrong rows for the 2nd+ rows.

SQL Fiddle [showing incorrect Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3a16/1) results.

I need this solution for both Oracle and SQL Server, and I was able to figure out the solution in SQL Server using the `sql:column` XPath [function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx).  This SQL Fiddle [shows the correct results on a SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33304/3) database.

Is there an Oracle equivalent of the SQL Server `sql:column` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over-thinking this problem.  Oracle allows you to use string concatenation inside the XPath.  The XPath ends up looking like `[@Line_ID="' || DtlAlias.Line_ID || '"]`

An updated [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3a16/2) that shows the correct results.